# ListView scrolling skips to the end even though it was at the beginning of the list

Tags: javafx-8

For some odd reason when I'm scrolling through my listview with over 20k items in the list, it suddenly scrolls to the end.

I'm not even halfway to the end and all of a sudden the scrollbar just skips to the end.

I'm using javafx8_20 the stable release.

Here's my cellfactory, all I did was add 20k plus items to the list and when I scroll through it, it seems fine for a little while but then it scrolls right to the end.

[image: The Table]

itemList.setCellFactory(new Callback, ListCell>() {

```
        @Override
        public ListCell<Item> call(ListView<Item> arg0) {
            ListCell<Item> cell = new ListCell<Item>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null || !empty) {
                        System.out.println(item.getId());
                        setText("Test " + item.getId());

                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        System.out.println("null");
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }

    });
```

Example Code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ListView<Integer> listview = new ListView<>();

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) { 
        listview.getItems().add(j);
    }
    layout.getChildren().add(listview);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 150, 250));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Comment: The `else` clause should call `setText(null)` (or use an empty string). I doubt that causes the issue though. Is it definitely the cell factory that's causing the problem? Does it work in the current release (1.8.0_11)?

Comment: Oh, I guess I missed that 1.8.0_20 was released...

Comment: If you comment out the cell factory (adding a `toString` method to your `Item` class if necessary) does it display the same behavior?

Comment: So it's probably not the cell factory. I can't reproduce this; can you post a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've switched to JDK 1.8.0_05 32bit and its resolved. It appears to be a JDK bug

Comment: OK, I see that, but *very* rarely. (Actually, I see it more with 10,000 items than 20,000.) You should probably post this at [jira](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) but emphasize it's pretty hard to reproduce. Link this discussion.